# Transition doesn't work in Firefox

Tags: javascript, css, firefox

I want to change div's background image smoothly when user hovers mouse on element, so I use this code

```
$("#bg").css({'background-image':'url("'+$(images[background_id]).attr("src")+'")', 'background-size':'cover', 'transition': '1.5s','-webkit-transition' : '1.5s'});
```

In Chrome it works fine, but in FF background is changing immediately

Comment: You forgot the -moz-transition: for the vendor specific transition, though I suggest that use class with the css then just change the attribute of the selector you have.

Comment: firefox doesn't need -moz- prefix for transition since version 16

Comment: You should try setting the transition before you change the background, not at the same time.

Comment: @VictorSoto I've already tried to use -moz-transition, it doesn't work

Comment: I think eric is right, it should already have the transition :D thanks for the -moz- prefix :D

Comment: @ericjbasti OK, I wrote this

$("#bg").css({ 'transition': '1.5s','-webkit-transition' : '1.5s', '-moz-transition' : '1.5s'});
$("#bg").css({'background-image' : 'url("'+$(images[background_id]).attr("src")+'")', 'background-size':'cover'});

Nothing changed

Comment: try setting it to transition: all 1.5s; http://jsfiddle.net/sK7Wk/254/  what version of FF is this?

Comment: Did a little more digging, and it looks like thats just how it works in FF when dealing with a background-image. http://jsfiddle.net/ericjbasti/sK7Wk/257/

Comment: @ericjbasti very interesting, both of your fiddles are working fine in FF(btw, I use version 39.0)

Comment: Funny because the second one doesn't work for me in FF (same version)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Mozilla docs, background-image transitions aren't supported by Firefox.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties